# How to make bash terminal ran from VSCode use Flutter version selected for the project

Tags: flutter, terminal, version, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble toggling Flutter versions on Mac OS Catalina in VSCode. The problem is that the terminal that I open in VSCode does not use the flutter version I select for the project. [image]

I've got version 1.22.4 system-wide installed but the project uses 2.0.3 with null-safety.
I can launch the project using Run command (with launch.json configuration) and it it will launch it using version 2.0.3 but when I want to do it from VSCode built-in terminal it uses 1.22.4. I even tried to reboot the system to check if it's not a problem with cached values. It's not.
I have no idea why VSCode does not set the variables for terminal session when it launches it.
Is it possible at all to make VSCode terminal use the versions of Flutter and Dart selected for the particular project?
Seems like it might be somehow configured in dart-code plugin. But I haven't found how

p.s. I've googled a lot on this issue and haven't found the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that the integrated terminal in vscode is part of the OS and not an environment.

You can create an alias for your flutter command,
The one you use most often, keep it flutter,
The less often, call it flutter2 or flutter nullsafety,

Since you have both of them working, that means both of your paths are exported and ready. Point flutter2 to the SDK located in the one you are using in your launch json.

Then you can use `flutter run`  or `flutter2 run` whenever you want.

```
alias flutter='~/user/sdks/flutterStable/bin/flutter'

alias flutter2='~/user/sdks/flutter1226/bin/flutter'
```

`flutter --v` will give you 2.0.3

`flutter2 --v` will give you 1.26

It should solve your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not an option. I need all standard commands without any aliases

Comment: Everything comes with the alias. `flutter doctor` will be different than `flutter2 doctor`, try it, it'll work

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look. Or please explain what commands you need that aliases don't solve for you exact problem.

Comment: Aliases are cumbersome and absolutely inconvenient. I need to be able to simply toggle flutter or dart version inside vscode by pressing a version button on the status bar without the need to configure anything in os. Right now I'm using fvm for downloading flutter versions and I can't even imagine what a pain it would be to set aliases for all of them

Comment: fvm allows to quickly toggle versions of flutter but for some reason vscode pays no mind to that

Answer (score 0):

1-add path of required flutter version to system in (/Users/user/.zshrc)

2-run command (source /Users/user/.zshrc) to asign this path to vscode

3-Close vscode & open and check flutter version and it will work fine